# How to make a button do two things after the other

Tags: vb.net, button, text

I'm a new programmer starting out in visual basic and I am trying to make a visual novel, but I have run into a few problems.

I am trying to make the text change to the next line of text when a button is pressed. Here is some example code I am using. The 'DisplayText' is where the speech is contained and 'ButtonNext' is the button to go to the next piece of text.

```
Private Sub ButtonNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonNext.Click
    If DisplayText.Text = "" Then
        DisplayText.Text = "Test"
    End If
End Sub
```

This Works. However, I want it so the same button can then go to another line after the "Test" line. I used this in the same private sub:

```
If DisplayText.Text = "Test" Then
    DisplayText.Text = "Second Test"
End If
```

I don't get any errors, but when i run the code and press the button, it instantly changes to the last line. I know why, I just don't know any code (And can't find any) on how to make the text go to the next line per press rather than all at once.

Hope this makes sense and I hope there is a way of doing this. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: The answer below are pretty good. You could've also just flip the if (do the second one first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub ButtonNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonNext.Click
    If DisplayText.Text = "" Then
        DisplayText.Text = "Test"
    Else If DisplayText.Text = "Test" Then
        DisplayText.Text = "Second Test"
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that your DisplayText gets changed to "Test" and immediately moves into the next `If` Statement, which then checks if it is "Test", by which stage is true. Using an `Else` statement prevents this problem.

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking for this for a couple of hours! Thank you so much

Comment: To show your appreciation, you could up-vote helpful answers, and mark the most helpful answer as accepted :)

Comment: @user3033047: Don't learn bad habits like that, better see answer by Douglas Barbin.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a prime example of when you should use a `Case` statement instead of `If` statement.

```
Select Case DisplayText.Text

    Case ""
        DisplayText.Text = "Test"

    Case "Test"
        DisplayText.Text = "Second Test"

End Select
```

Comment: If this answer wasn't there, I'd be tempted to post my own like that. Otherwise +1. Please also note that `Case "": DisplayText.Text = "Test"` syntax is possible in VB.NET (single line action).

Comment: @Neolisk I suppose that I am in the habit of making multi-line statements in VB because my coworkers typically find them easier to read than single-line statements.  But you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have your two `If` statements like this:

```
If DisplayText.Text = "" Then

DisplayText.Text = "Test"

End If

If DisplayText.Text = "Test" Then

DisplayText.Text = "Second Test"

End If
```

The first `If` statement executes, changing the text to "Test". Then the second `If` statement executes: If the text is "Test", then change it to "Second Test". So if you enter the sub with the text box blank, it will be changed to "Test", then before you can even see it, it will be changed to "Second Test".

The solution is to use the `Else If` statement:

```
If DisplayText.Text = "" Then

DisplayText.Text = "Test"

Else If DisplayText.Text = "Test" Then

DisplayText.Text = "Second Test"

End If
```

This will only enter the second `If` statement if the first condition (`DisplayText.Text = ""`) is not true.

Comment: Thank you so much, I have literally been looking for this answer for a couple of hours! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using threading in the system to pause the text before it changes.

```
Private Sub ButtonNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonNext.Click
    If DisplayText.Text = "" Then
    DisplayText.Text = "Test"
End If

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

If DisplayText.Text = "Test" Then
    DisplayText.Text = "Second Test"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answer's the question, the result will still stay the same, and will just appear later.